# TypeScript error on Firebase Cloud Function: Property 'toJSON' is missing in type 'FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a Firebase Cloud Function, and I'm trying to convert a datetime string to a Firebase Timestamp.

I have been following advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54637416/1526396) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66482872/1526396) answer, but TypeScript is complaining with this error:

> Property 'toJSON' is missing in type 'FirebaseFirestore.Timestamp' but
> required in type
> 'import("/Users/John/Dev/my-app/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index").Timestamp'.
> ts(2741)

This is what my code looks like:

```TypeScript
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';
interface FirestoreSerp {
  createdAt: Timestamp;
  keyword: string;
}
const datetime = '2019-11-15 12:57:46 +00:00'
const firestoreSerp: FirestoreSerp = {
  createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(datetime)), // <-- ERROR HERE
  keyword: 'rickety cricket',
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client SDK (`firebase/firestore`) uses slightly different type definitions to the admin SDK (`firebase-admin`) and that is what is causing your conflict.

Use the same package to extract the types.

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

interface FirestoreSerp {
  createdAt: admin.firebase.Timestamp;
  keyword: string;
}

const datetime = '2019-11-15 12:57:46 +00:00'
const firestoreSerp: FirestoreSerp = {
  createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(datetime)),
  keyword: 'rickety cricket',
};
```

To alias the type:

```js
type Timestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp;
```